# How to templatize the container type in a function declaration?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to write a function that accepts any container holding strings.  Something like this:

```
template <typename Container> void foo(Container<string>& stuff);
```

But this isn't the right syntax.  What's the right syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [template template parameter](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=376878):

```
template < template <typename> class Container> void foo (Container<string>& stuff);
```

Comment: `template <typename> class Container`.

Comment: Yep, the second typename needs to be class instead, and it works.  Thanks!

Comment: The last sentence of that linked page is wrong. See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469743/standard-library-containers-with-additional-optional-template-parameters)