# Explain the sample code from cppreference.com about iterator tags

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

could someone explain me few points in the sample from cppreference site?
The technique describes functions overloading depends of iterator type. 
First two typedefs with "using" are clear for understanding.
The questions relate to alg functions:

1. in the list of template parameters -"typename = ..." without parameter name, does this mean that used default value without ability to overwrite this in function call?
2. do I understand the using of second template parameter right - the function will be generated in only case of type equality of passed iterator type and expected iterator tag?

   3. could you explain the using of third template parameter in second function alg and the comment there:

> "typename = void> // dummy value to avoid template re-definition error
>   "

The piece of code is here (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags):

```
template<typename Condition, typename T = void>
using EnableIf_t = typename std::enable_if<Condition::value, T>::type;

template<typename Iterator, typename IteratorTag>
using IsSameIteratorCond = 
    std::is_same<IteratorTag, 
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category>;

template<
    typename BDIter, 
    typename = EnableIf_t<IsSameIteratorCond<BDIter, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag>>>
void alg(BDIter, BDIter)
{
    std::cout << "alg() called for bidirectional iterator\n";
}

template<
    typename RAIter, 
    typename = EnableIf_t<IsSameIteratorCond<RAIter, std::random_access_iterator_tag>>, 
    typename = void> // dummy value to avoid template re-definition error
void alg(RAIter, RAIter)
{
    std::cout << "alg() called for random-access iterator\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    alg(v.begin(), v.end());

    std::list<int> l;
    alg(l.begin(), l.end());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `typename = ...` declares an unnamed template parameter. Client code could still override it, but the parameter can't be used in the function definition. This is used here because the second template parameter is used to leverage SFINAE rather than to work out a type to use in the definition.
2. Correct, if the iterator type is not the same as the expected one, the function will be removed from the overload candidate set.
3. The dummy parameter is needed because default values are not part of the template signature, so the two versions of `alg` would be trying to define the same function template.

Using default values and dummy parameters is pretty ugly to me, I'd prefer to use tag-dispatch:

```
template<typename BDIter>
void alg(BDIter, BDIter, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag)
{
    std::cout << "alg() called for bidirectional iterator\n";
}

template <typename RAIter>
void alg(RAIter, RAIter, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    std::cout << "alg() called for random-access iterator\n";
}

template <typename It>
void alg(It a, It b)
{
    return alg(a, b, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category{});
}
```

Comment: thank you. didn't know about "default values are not part of the template signature," could you drop me a link on this in C++ standard or cppreference site?

Comment: I can't find a succinct reference, but think about the analogue in function declarations; if functions differ only in their default arguments, they are obviously trying to declare a function with the same signature.

Comment: @amigo421 There is some good discussion here (but not succinct!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301706/default-values-in-templates-with-template-arguments-c  And here is a expert level paper about template default params: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1466.pdf

Answer (score 1):

1. No, the user is able to overwrite the parameter. Naming a parameter
   is optional. You don't have to do it if you won't use it.
2. Yes. The tag has to be equal to `std::bidirectional_iterator_tag`
   for the first overload to kick in, and `std::random_access_iterator_tag` for
   the second one.
3. Without the third template parameter, the two
   function declarations would be the same, which is illegal. They
   either have to differ by parameters, return type, name, or template
   parameters (which is the case here).