# C++ template template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to understand C++ template templates by implementing a generic container class. Here is the code:

```
    using namespace std;

    template <typename T, template <typename STORETYPE> class Container>
    class Store {
    public:
        ~Store() {};
        Store() {};
        void someFunc( const T & ) {};
        //...
    private:
        Container<T> storage;
    };




    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        Store<int,deque> myStore;   // error here, won't compile!
    }
```

The code above generates a compiler error message. The error message is:

"template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter
    Store aStack1;

I don't know why. What's wrong?

Comment: If you pass deque<T> only you can then use a deque trait to get its inner type (deque::value_type) instead of giving your container two template parameters, T and Container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is that `std::deque` (and other standard containers) doesn't just take a single template argument. As well as the stored type, you can specify an allocator functor type to use.

If you don't care about these additional arguments, you can just take a variadic template template and be on your way:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Container>
//                             variadic ^^^
class Store {
```

If you also want to support passing of optional arguments to your container type, you can forward them on like this:

```
template <template <typename ...> class Container, typename T, typename... ContainerArgs>
class Store {
    //...
    Container<T,ContainerArgs...> storage;
};
```

Then instantiate like so:

```
Store<deque,int> myStore;
Store<deque,int,MyIntAllocator> mySpecialStore;
```

However, you might just want to extract the template arguments using specialization:

```
template <typename Container>
class Store;

template <template <typename...> class ContainerType, typename T, typename... OtherArgs>
class Store<ContainerType<T,OtherArgs...>>
{
    //...
};
```

This will let client code instantiate like this:

```
Store<deque<int>> myStore;
Store<deque<int,MyIntAllocator>> mySpecialStore;
Store<T> myOtherStore; //where T is some specialized container type
```

Comment: Note however that in the first case certain compilers (such as MSVC) will reject the instantiation of `Container<T>` as they expect two template parameters for `std::deque`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::deque` is defined as

```
template <class T, class Allocator = allocator<T> > class deque;
```

So you should change the definition of `Store` to match:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Container>
class Store {
```

But actually you don't even need template template parameters for this. You can achieve even more generality just passing a container type as parameter, so for example `Storage` would support even `std::map`:

```
template <typename  Container>
class Store {
public:
    using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
    ~Store() {};
    Store() {};
    void someFunc( const value_type& ) {};
    //...
private:
    Container storage;
};

Store<std::map<int, float>> myStore;
```

Comment: Instead of `value_type`, one could also use the result-type of `operator[]`, that is `using value_type = decltype(std::declval<Container>().operator[](size_t{}))`. This possibly reduces the constraints on `Container`.

Comment: @davidhigh all standard containers have `value_type`, but not all have `operator[]`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the answer by @TartanLlama, you can also use an alias for `deque`.

```
template<typename T>
using deque_alias = deque<T>;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Store<int,deque_alias> myStore;   // now it will compile!
}
```

Then also the default template parameters (here `std::allocator<T>`) are used correctly. (Some compilers like MSVC have problems with that and will fail otherwise, as they expect two template parameters, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5301706/2412846) for example).