# How to overcome circular dependence with declarations?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I declare classes that refer to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503533/how-can-i-declare-classes-that-refer-to-each-other)

Below is my code in a .h file. Compiler will complain about having SP object in CPattern. I can't place SP's declaration above CPattern as it's also declaring CPattern object in it. How do I solve this? Thank you for your help!

```
class CPattern
{
public:
    CPattern(void);
    ~CPattern(void);

    SP & Create(void);
};


class SP
{
private:
    const CPattern*    pPat;
public:
    SP()
    {
    }
    ~SP()
    {
        // pointer no longer requried
        delete pPat;
    }    
};
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3110269/1641234) on forward declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `class SP;` at the top of your file.   This is a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) which tells the compiler what an `SP` is but doesn't describe its implementation.

Comment: Ahhh.... Totally forgotten about this! Thank you!