# "class name" must be a previously defined class or struct

Tags: c++, inheritance

Please,look at this simple class:

```
class TernaryPolynomial;
class IntegerPolynomial;

class DenseTernaryPolynomial:public IntegerPolynomial,public TernaryPolynomial
{
 public:
 DenseTernaryPolynomial();
static DenseTernaryPolynomial generateRandom(int,int,int);
};
```

Can you please explain me why does the compiler complains that TernaryPolynomial must be a previously defined class or struct? I thought it shouldn't care at all since i put a forward declaration of that class. 
Here's the TernaryPolynomial class

```
class Polynomial;
class IntegerPolynomial;

class TernaryPolynomial:public Polynomial
{
 public:
 TernaryPolynomial();
 virtual ~TernaryPolynomial();
 virtual IntegerPolynomial toIntegerPolynomial() = 0;
 };
```

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389957/forward-declaration-of-a-base-class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For derivation a forward declaration is not enough, you need to include the full class definition.

Forward declarations can only be used when you define a pointer or a reference to the class as a member or method parameter. As soon as you really begin using things (by dereferencing, accessing a member over a reference or deriving for example) you need to include the whole class definition.

Answer (score 2):

Forward declarations are only useful if you declare a pointer to the class. In this case, the full class definition is not needed.

Deriving from a class makes a `is-a` relationship. `DenseTernaryPolynomial` cannot be something it has no knowledge of, other than that it exists.

The `sizeof` for `DenseTernaryPolynomial` must be know by the end of the class definition, as well as all members (inherited or not), but a forward declaration doesn't provide this information.

For inheritance, you must include the header where the base class is defined.