# Invalide use of incomplete type Qt

Tags: c++, qt, linker, base-class

I have a little problem :

**finddialog.h**

```
#ifndef FINDDIALOG_H
#define FINDDIALOG_H

class QDialog;
class QWidget;
class QLineEdit;
class QPushButton;
class QCheckBox;
class QLabel;

class FindDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    FindDialog(QWidget *parent);

private slots:
    void findClicked();
    void enableFindButton(const QString &text);

signals :
    void findNext(const QString &str, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs);
    void findPrev(const QString &str, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs);

private:
    QLabel *findLabel;
    QLineEdit *textEdit;
    QCheckBox *caseCheckBox;
    QCheckBox *backwCheckBox;
    QPushButton *findButton;
    QPushButton *closeButton;

};

#endif // FINDDIALOG_H
```

**finddialog.c**

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "finddialog.h"


FindDialog::FindDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
}

void FindDialog::findClicked()
{

}

void FindDialog::enableFindButton(const QString &text)
{

}
```

I receive a `QDialog`/`QPushButton` invalid use of incomplete type error.

I have already included `QtWidget` in `.cpp` file so why is it not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Forward) declaration is not enough for a base-class type. You have to provide the definition (make `QDialog` a complete type), so:

```
#include <QDialog>
```

in the header file. See [Forward Declaration of a Base Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389957/forward-declaration-of-a-base-class).

Based on the code you posted, I don't know where the error about `QPushButton` being incomplete comes from (if you `#include <QtWidgets>`, of course).

If you do not `#include <QtWidgets>` (which has `#include <QPushButton>`, etc...), you cannot instantiate any of these incomplete types, like so:

```
new QPushButton(this);
```

That again, requires a definition (What's the size of the memory `QPushButton` needs? What constructor to call? That's known only if there's a definition in that compilation unit - `.cpp` file).

Comment: For the sake of clarity, it is not a declaration, it's a forward declaration.

Comment: @skypjack "forward" just indicates the usage, right? It's still a declaration.

Comment: @LogicStuff *For the sake of clarity*

Comment: @LogicStuff Absolutely, it is called so because of the use we do of it. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) for further details.

Comment: thank you, another think learned about c++, but i don't know why i have error for QPushButton and any other Qt type i want to use, but when i include <QtWidgets> in the header file everything work fine

Answer (score 0):

By the forward declaration of `QPushButton` and others in `finddialog.h`, the compiler expects to find their constructors and other methods in some linked files.
`#include` the required header files to get it working.

Comment: @jafar there is no inline method derefencing the pointer in header file, and in source file i have included <QtWidgets>