# Using nested class as parent class template parameter?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++20

I have a nested class definition that I wanted to pass down as the parent class (*class containing the nested class, **not** the class that's being inherited*) template parameter. Since the template does not seem to be aware of the nested class's existance, I tried to pass it down as an incomplete type, only to read later that doing so is usually a bad idea and is only rarely permitted (such as in the case of `shared_ptr`).

I know this can be very easily solved by simply declaring the nested class externally (which is what I do) but I am asking this because I want to learn if there is any way of achieving the same effect because I an fond of how they do not pollute the namespace how they are "associated" with the parent class definition without exposing anything.

Here's an example to perhaps make it more clear on what I am talking about:

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class shared_class {
protected:
  shared_ptr<T> d = make_shared<T>();

  T* container() { return d.get(); }
};

                                   // A is the "parent" class.
class A : public shared_class<C> { // Compiler error: C is undefined. 
                                   // Similarly, A::C will complain that no C is in A.
  class C {                        // Nested class
  public:
    int i = 0;
  };
};
```

Is there another way of doing this with templates in a way that the entire definition of the nested class is contained entirely within the parent class definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution for your specific case with the requirements you gave, as far as I can tell.

Directly using `C` as template argument can't work in any way, simply because at that point the compiler hasn't seen yet that `C` is declared as a member class of `A` and because there is no way to declare the nested class before that point.

---

It doesn't work in your specific case, but with some limitations, you could add an indirection to the type of the `shared_class` template parameter via a traits template or directly via an alias declaration, which would allow you to delay the determination that `T` is supposed to be `C` until after the definition of `A` and keep `C` as nested class.

Unfortunately that doesn't work if you want to use the type `T` of `shared_class` in one of the declarations that would be instantiated with the class template specialization, here `shared_ptr<T> d` and `T* container()`. The latter could be saved by declaring the return type `auto`, but the former can't.

The idea would be to let `shared_class` use `typename T::shared_class_type` everywhere instead of `T`.

The class `A` would be defined as

```
class A : public shared_class<A> {
public:     
  class C {                        
  public:
    int i = 0;
  };
  using shared_class_type = C;
};
```

Alternatively you would define a `template<typename T> struct shared_class_traits;`, potentially with a default implementation containing `using shared_class_type = typename T::shared_class_type;` to be potentially specialized for `A` after its definition with a `using shared_class_type = A::C;` member, so that `shared_class` can use `typename shared_class_traits<T>::shared_class_type` everywhere. This is more flexible than "reserving" a specific member name of all classes using `shared_class_type`.

But as I explained above it will not work as long as `shared_class` uses `shared_class_type` at all in a context that is instantiated with the class template specialization. So inside a member function body or default member initializer would be fine, but in a data member or a member function type is not.

Comment: In a case where `T` is usually treated as a pointed-to type (like in `T* container()`) this may be a good alternative, although I don't quite understand what you mean by an indirection in this context.
EDIT: I see you edited your answer to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @daedsidog See edit. The restrictions are stronger though. You may not use `T` at all in a data member or member function declaration, only in function bodies, etc.

Comment: @daedsidog Actually I first thought of doing it differently. The version I gave now doesn't need any additional namespace scope declaration, but still has the same limitations.

Answer (score 3):

In short: no you can't do this. There are a few similar questions you can find on SO, but it all comes down to being able to forward-declare the nested class, which you can't do without a definition. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021793/how-do-i-forward-declare-an-inner-class).

In other words, with great hand-waving, you might think you could do something like this:

```
class A;
class A::C; // Error: not real C++

class A : public shared_class<A::C> { // Error: incomplete base class
  class C {
  public:
    int i = 0;
  };
};
```

But you can't. You need to separate the declaration of `C`, and it needs a definition if it's going to be used as a base class. See also questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389957/forward-declaration-of-a-base-class).

If it's just namespace encapsulation you most care about, you can always just use a dedicated `namespace`, that's what they're for.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat, that confused me too, ha. As a "solutionist" myself, I hate giving an answer that says "no you can't do this", I imagine that's why it got downvoted. Ideally we all want to find a way around limitations.

Comment: @JonReeves I feel called out here! Part of the reason for this question is the nagging feeling in the back of my head that there is some quirky template trick to do these sort of things, and usually the "no you can't" answers put me at ease. So, it wasn't me!

Comment: No worries @daedsidog, for what it's worth there's enough people on this platform, I did not immediately assume it was you downvoting. I'd be a little surprised if someone could work around the limitations that lead to the "no" answer here (there's actually more than one), but in general I agree, "no you can't" answers are always unsettling.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers pointed out, there is no direct solution for this problem, as there is no way to forward declare the class C.

To still be able to write `A::C` my solution would be:

```cpp
namespace {
    class C_Anon{
    public:
        int i = 0;
    };
}

template <class T> class shared_class {
protected:
    shared_ptr<T> d = make_shared<T>();

    T* container() { return d.get(); }
};

// A is the "parent" class.
class A : public shared_class<C_Anon> {
    using C = C_Anon; //Allows for writing A::C
};
```